# Export variable from scons script to source file

Tags: c++, scripting, scons

I have an environment variable ( key value) pair in scons script. I want to export the value of this variable in a cpp source file.

How do I do that?
Because scons scripts may not be available after compiling.

I have tried to do something using export but it's still not happening.

The value of the environment variable is a string.

Comment: can you show an example SConstruct?  Are you saying you have something like `env['XYZ']=1` and you want that to be generated into your source file? your want to provide it to the compilation via a preprocessor define? other?

Comment: @bdbaddog yeah I have something like env['XYZ'] = 1 and I want to use that in my source file ( CPP file).

Comment: How would you do that using any build system?  You're most likely options are to use that in CPPDEFINES (aka -DXYZ=1) or to generate a headerfile with such and include it in your source file. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Actually I want to import that in a CPP header file only (.h) file. Which would then be included further as per need. So I basically want to export a value from a scons script to .h file

Comment: @bdbaddog, In addition to my last comment,  I also want to ask, what do you mean "generate" a header file. So, I already have a header file, the basic need is to get the variable imported in the existing header file from scons script.

Comment: Technically, you may use something like find-and-replace to change the existing headers but I don't think SCons can properly handle a task that modifies the source file instead of creating a new one. A better idea would be to have a template file with some marker like `<PASTE_THE_VALUE_HERE>` and create a new file based on it, taking this one as a read-only source. Personally, I would ditch the template altogether and just generate some simple header like `int xyz = 1;`, which can be included whenever you need it, e.g. in the header you originally wanted to edit.

Comment: You cannot modify a file in place. You can either alter a source file to generat e a differently name file which you then include, generate a file just from the value, or set a preprocessor define. Those would be your only repeatable options.

Comment: The templating capability does exist: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#f-Substfile, but as mentioned, you'd be generating a *new* file using this.

Comment: Okay, I am just clarifying. I have a Sconscript and it has an environment variable env("XYZ")=1 and I now want that if I use the variable "XYZ" in Header file, it should print "1". It's fine if a new file is to be built. So how to do this? Help please.

Comment: @bdbaddog. Please see the last comment.

Comment: @MatsWichmann.. please refer my latest comment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `env.Textfile()`

See manpage entry here: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#b-textfile

Example SConstruct

```
env=Environment(XYZ=2)
env.Textfile('outfile.txt', source=['int xyz=$XYZ;\n'], varlist=['XYZ'])
```

**NOTE:** whatever variables you use in source via *$VARIABLE_NAME*, you'll need to list in *varlist*, otherwise changing the variable(s) values won't cause *outfile.txt* to be rebuilt.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I studied the theory. It was really helpful.  Although, I tried implementing this and it says "SconsEnvironment has no attribute 'Textfile".  Ps: Scons version is scons-2.4.1.

Comment: Update: Working if env = Environment (tools = 'textfile") is added.  This helps in error free build. BUT I cannot find the outfile.txt file any where!. Any help?

Comment: Also, if I try to mention the absolute path of source and target, I get the "Two different environments were specified for target, but they appear to have the same action : _action(target, source, env)".

Comment: Why use such an ancient version of SCons?  You'll likely want to use `tools=['default','textfile']` so you'll get all the default builders + textfile.

Comment: If you're getting the two different enviromentes are you using variant_dirs ?

Comment: Also since the above answer answers your question, please mark it as the answer?